# ejs " <%= " not working on action attribute of a form, but is working on other parts of the modal

Tags: node.js

I am trying to implement inline delete on a table using a modal. Here is my code.

```
<% for (let ta of task) { %>
                            <tr>
                                <td><%= ta.taskID %></td>
                                <td><%= ta.taskName %></td>
                                <td><%= ta.taskType %></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<%= ta.taskU %>">
                                        Delete
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="<%= ta.taskU %>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Are you sure you want to delete <strong><%= ta.taskName %></strong>?</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <form action="/managetask/<%= ta._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST" id="deltask">
                                            <button onclick="delt()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">CONFIRM DELETE</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <% } %>
```

---

here is my route:

```
app.delete('/managetask/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    // await Task.findOneAndDelete(id);
    console.log(id);
    res.redirect('/managetask');
});
```

I tried logging the id and it is showing the id of the first item on the table instead of the actual item am trying to delete.

please help!

Comment: Are actualy adding a modal for each item in the table? I mean if you have a 100 items in the table are you adding 100 modals? If so i would strongly recommend against doing so. Single modal should be enough, just use a bit of javascript. Also when you hit the Delete button and the modal opens does the form's action attribute have the correct id? What is the `delt()` function doing after you click?

Comment: This is the delt()

function delt() {
                                document.getElementById("deltask").submit();
                            }

I added that because the form was not working inside the modal.

Comment: Well for that to work you need to set the button type to submit `<button  type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">CONFIRM DELETE</button>`